# Returning and using a nullable Type

Tags: dart

Settings are sent in a json file including the type it should be.
I convert the type found in json to the native type like so:

```dart
  Type _jsonTypeToDart(String? type) {
    if (type == null) {
      return dynamic;
    }

    switch (type) {
      case 'string':
      case '?string':
        return String;
      case 'float':
      case '?float':
        return double;
      case 'int':
      case '?int':
        return int;
      case 'json':
      case '?json':
        return Map;
      case 'bool':
      case '?bool':
        return bool;
    }

    return dynamic;
  }
```

How can I for example use `String?` to return as a `Type`?

This type is then used to check the value of the setting, or cast it if needed.

```dart
dynamic value = setting['value'];
Type? type = _jsonTypeToDart(setting['type'];
if (value.runtimeType == type) {
    return value;
}
```

More info:
To cast the value into the correct type, or check if the value from json is the correct value. For example:

```json
      {
         "key":"my_setting",
         "value":3,
         "type":"float"
      },
```

`value.runtimeType` would be an int, while it should be used as a double. So then `if (type == double)` I can parse it as a double instead of int.

Comment: What are you going to use the `Type` for? It is rarely useful to handle `Type` objects in Dart.

Comment: @julemand101 I added an example to the original post

Comment: Instead of converting to `Type` objects and later use these, I would just make a method which takes your `type` field and the `value` and will then return the object you want. Note, you should really not use `runtimeType` since it can give you some issues where you are seeing the real types on runtime which can be some internal class from the Dart runtime itself. Instead, use e.g. `if(value is int)` to test the type since that tests if `value` is compatible with the type and not is specific this precise type.

Comment: @vixez FYI, `String` and `String?` are both `Type`s. A declaration `Type? type`  means that `null` can be assigned to the `type` variable, not that it represents a nullable type.  If you really want, you could do `Type identityType<T>() => T;` (and then use it as `identityType<String?>()`), but as julemand101 said, `Type` objects generally are not useful.  Also see [How do I check whether a generic type is nullable in Dart NNBD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66240962/).

Comment: Okay thanks, I will change the code