# Dart check nullable Type

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I looking to find a way to check if the type is nullable using switch statement but I got an error by doing that. Doesn't anyone know how to check if the type of object in the nullable state?

```dart
void dataFactory(Type type, data){
    switch(type){
      case A:
        return A.fromJson(data);
        case A?: // Getting error Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'
          return A.fromJson(data);
      case B:
        return B.fromJson(data);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function `Type getType<T>() => T;`, but since `getType<A?>()` would not be considered a constant value, you would not be able to use it with a `switch` statement:

```dart
Type getType<T>() => T;

dynamic dataFactory(Type type, Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  if (type == A || type == getType<A?>()) {
     return A.fromJson(data);
  } else if (type == B) {
     return B.fromJson(data);
  }
  ...
}
```

Another approach would be to use a `Map` of callbacks:

```dart
Type getType<T>() => T;

final _factoryMap = <Type, dynamic Function(Map<String, dynamic>)>{
  A: A.fromJson,
  getType<A?>(): A.fromJson,
  B: B.fromJson,
};

dynamic dataFactory(Type type, Map<String, dynamic> data) =>
    _factoryMap[type]?.call(data);
```

Comment: This second approach is nice but doesn't work in my case. I need to cast to dynamic `"{A: A.fromJson as dynamic}"` but it get error at runtime.

Comment: @user102232 Casting `Function`s is almost always wrong.  The second approach should work if `A.fromJson` is declared as `static A fromJson(dynamic data) { ... }` (and likewise for `B.fromJson`).  If they take a different type of argument, then you would either would need to change the type of `_factoryMap` or you would need to wrap `A.fromJson` in anonymous functions that *do* have the correct signature.  I don't know what `A.fromJson` and `B.fromJson` look like so can't give you more specific help.

Comment: The json function look like this `factory A.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)`

Comment: @user102232 Okay, your `dataFactory` function didn't provide a type for `data`, so Dart (and I) assumed it to be `dynamic`.  If `A.fromJson` and `B.fromJson` both expect `Map<String, dynamic>` arguments, then the second approach just needs to use callbacks that expect a `Map<String, dynamic>` argument.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You question is:

> I looking to find a way to check if the type is nullable using switch statement. Doesn't anyone know how to check if the type of object in the nullable state?

Even though I didn't use the `switch` statement I guess you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73161442/11793117) and verify if a generic type is nullable by creating a new list instance.

> **Note:** I'm assuming we can replace the `Type` type parameter instance with a generic type `T`. Since Flutter disable reflections this is the only way we can use in order to verify a given type `T` nature (Nullable or not).

```dart
bool isNullable<T>() => <T?>[] is List<T>;
```

You can also maybe adapt this function to fill your needs:

```dart
bool checkTypes<X, Y>() => <X>[] is List<Y> && <Y>[] is List<X>;
```

And use it as:

```dart
T dataFactory<T>(dynamic data) {
  if(checkTypes<T, A>()) {
    // Non-nullable [A]
  } else if(checkTypes<T, A?>()) {
    // Nullable [A]
  }

  /// Repeat with [B], [C], etc.
}
```

You can also test it:

```dart
void main() {
  print(checkTypes<A, A>()); // true
  print(checkTypes<B?, B>()); // false
  print(checkTypes<B?, B?>()); // true
}
```

Comment: I believe this solution will also but it's look so like a hack. And @jamesdlin is better and simple to work with.